multiprocess.pool.RemoteTraceback and TypeError: Couldn't cast array of type string to null when loading Hugging Face dataset
I’m encountering an error while trying to load and process the GAIR/MathPile dataset using the Hugging Face datasets library. The error seems to occur during type casting in pyarrow within a multiprocessing environment. Below is the code I’m using
from datasets import Dataset, load_dataset
import os

def get_hf_dataset_gair(path: str = '~/data/GAIR/MathPile/train/') -> Dataset:
    path: str = os.path.expanduser(path)
    dataset = load_dataset(path, split='train', num_proc=os.cpu_count())
    print(dataset[0])  # Preview a single example from the dataset
    
    # Remove unnecessary columns
    all_columns = dataset.column_names
    all_columns.remove('text')
    dataset = dataset.remove_columns(all_columns)
    
    # Shuffle and select 10k examples
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(seed=42)
    dataset = dataset.select(10_000)
    return dataset

# get it
get_hf_dataset_gair()

Download GAIR
source $AFS/.bashrc
conda activate beyond_scale_2

mkdir -p ~/data/GAIR/MathPile
huggingface-cli download --resume-download --repo-type dataset GAIR/MathPile --local-dir ~/data/GAIR/MathPile --local-dir-use-symlinks False

cd ~/data/GAIR/MathPile/
find . -type f -name "*.gz" -exec gzip -d {} \;


I get the following error when running the code:
multiprocess.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lfs/hyperturing1/0/user/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale_2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/builder.py", line 1869, in _prepare_split_single
    writer.write_table(table)
  ...
TypeError: Couldn't cast array of type string to null

Here’s the full stack trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lfs/hyperturing1/0/user/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale_2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/builder.py", line 1869, in _prepare_split_single
    writer.write_table(table)
  File "/lfs/hyperturing1/0/user/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale_2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/arrow_writer.py", line 580, in write_table
    pa_table = table_cast(pa_table, self._schema)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lfs/hyperturing1/0/user/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale_2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/table.py", line 2283, in table_cast
    return cast_table_to_schema(table, schema)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ...
TypeError: Couldn't cast array of type string to null

It seems to be related to type casting between pyarrow types. I suspect it has something to do with the dataset schema, but I’m not sure how to resolve the error. I've verified that the dataset is correctly downloaded, and I’m using the following environment:
Hugging Face datasets version: 2.x.x
Python 3.11
OS: Linux (running on a server)
Multiprocessing is set to use all available CPUs (num_proc=os.cpu_count())
Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone have suggestions on how to fix it?

ref: https://huggingface.co/datasets/GAIR/MathPile/discussions/3
ref: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/multiprocess-pool-remotetraceback-and-typeerror-couldnt-cast-array-of-type-string-to-null-when-loading-hugging-face-dataset/108166
ref: multiprocess.pool.RemoteTraceback and TypeError: Couldn't cast array of type string to null when loading Hugging Face dataset


Can you provide a [mcve], please?

@UlrichEckhardt added the missing bash download data cmds and import statements. It's complete, should be fully reproducible.

main ref: https://huggingface.co/datasets/GAIR/MathPile/discussions/3

Possible Solutions
Disable type checking when loading the dataset, ignoring the mismatch:
dataset = load_dataset(path, split='train', num_proc=os.cpu_count(), 
                           features=datasets.Features({"text": datasets.Value("string")}))

If that doesn't work, try creating a custom loader that sets the data types:
def custom_load(file):
    import json
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
    return {"text": [item["text"] for item in data]}

dataset = load_dataset("json", data_files=path, split='train', 
                       num_proc=os.cpu_count(), 
                       features=datasets.Features({"text": datasets.Value("string")}),
                       gen_kwargs={"streaming": True},
                       loading_script=custom_load)

If there are supposed to be null values in your dataset, make sure they are properly represented with null, not simply an empty value.
Correct:
{"id": 1, "name": "abcd", "data": null}

Incorrect:
{"id": 1, "name": "abcd", "data": "null"}
{"id": 1, "name": "abcd", "data": ""}

Dubugging
You can check the schema by doing:
import pyarrow as pa

dataset = load_dataset(path, split='train')
print(dataset.features)
print(pa.Schema.from_dict(dataset.features))


TypeError: Couldn't cast array of type A to B occurs when the data type changes unexpectedly. In other words, the library has already locked in a field as one type, but another type comes in.
In your case, the dataset consists of many different datasets from various sources. They are not supposed to be compatible with each other. Indeed, the meta field differs for each of them. Unfortunately, at the moment, HF datasets do not have a parameter that would discard extra fields during the loading phase.
It is assumed that you will load each source separately, process it, and bring it to the format you need, only then combining them. I suggest doing exactly that:
    datasets = []
    # Iterate over all sources
    for subset in (path / 'train').iterdir():
        dataset = load_dataset(str(subset), num_proc=os.cpu_count(), split="train")

        # Remove unnecessary columns
        # ...
        datasets.append(dataset)
    dataset = concatenate_datasets(datasets)

This could work, but there are a few nuances. Each of them makes the code more complicated, so be ready to dig
StackExchange
All sources store the text in the text field, except for StackExchange. StackExchange stores a question field and a list of answers. Therefore, if we want to concatenate this dataset with the others, we need to come up with a way to generate a text field for it.
TextBooks
All files within the other sources are compatible with each other, meaning they have the same fields in meta. But in TextBooks, there are 2 files: one for regular books and another for synthetic markdown. There are different ways to work around this problem. For example, you could simply read the files separately.
Another TypeError: Couldn't cast array of type string to null.
Even after splitting by folders and files, this error occurred when processing a JSON file with synthetic markdown. I spent the most time debugging this issue. I believe it’s worth writing a bug report to the developers. In general, changing the type from string to null is allowed within a dataset — there are even examples of this in the documentation. However, as it turns out, if the dataset is large and unevenly distributed, this allowance stops working. The schema gets locked in after reading a chunk. Consequently, if all values in the first chunk of a field are, for example, null, the field will be locked as type null, and if a string appears in that field in the second chunk, it will trigger this error. Fortunately, there is a parameter that controls the chunk size — we can simply increase it.
So, here is the final working code:
import os
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Literal

import numpy as np
from datasets import Dataset, load_dataset, concatenate_datasets


def _format_stackexchange(row):
    # Create new field 'text' based on 'question' and 'answer'
    answers = [answer["Body"] for answer in row['answers']]
    final_answer = "\n\n".join(answers)
    row['text'] = f"Question: {row['question']}\n\nAnswer: {final_answer}"
    return row


def _load_textbooks(subset: Path) -> Dataset:
    datasets = []
    # Iterate over json files
    for source in subset.rglob("*.jsonl"):
        print(f"Loading {source}...")
        dataset = load_dataset(
            "json",
            data_files=[str(source)],
            chunksize=10 << 24,  # 160Mb
            split="train",
        )
        dataset = dataset.remove_columns(["meta"])
        datasets.append(dataset)
    return concatenate_datasets(datasets)


def get_hf_dataset_gair(
        path: str = '~/data/GAIR/MathPile/',
        split: Literal['train', 'validation'] = 'train'
    ) -> Dataset:
    path: Path = Path(path).expanduser()

    datasets = []
    # Iterate over all sources
    for subset in (path / split).iterdir():
        print(f"Loading {subset}...")
        if subset.name == "textbooks":
            dataset = _load_textbooks(subset)
        else:
            dataset = load_dataset(str(subset), num_proc=os.cpu_count(), split="train")
        print(dataset[0])  # Preview a single example from the dataset
        print(f"{subset.name} fields: {dataset[0].keys()}")

        # Remove unnecessary columns
        all_columns = dataset.column_names
        if subset.name == "stackexchange":
            dataset = dataset.map(_format_stackexchange)
            dataset = dataset.remove_columns(all_columns)
        else:
            all_columns.remove('text')
            dataset = dataset.remove_columns(all_columns)
        datasets.append(dataset)
    dataset = concatenate_datasets(datasets)
    # Shuffle and select 10k examples
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(seed=42)
    dataset = dataset.select(np.arange(10_000))
    return dataset

# get it
get_hf_dataset_gair()


